# Is there's any way to lock particular tab so that it doesn't close with cmd/ctrl+w shortcut

Tags: macos, google-chrome, opera, browser-tabs, tabs

On my mac when I use Opera and pinned a tab it doesn't close with cmd+w. But in Chrome even when I pinned an important (like working on some document writing) tab and accidently press cmd+w, it just closes the tab.

So is there is any way to prevent that? or any idea? I've tried to find plugins but most of them doesn't work.

FIY I don't want to disable the shortcut btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Chrome extension
[Lock Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lock-tab/nhbdiieigbgalknjplfpgmjnpbnkchnb) :

> Prevents a tab from being closed accidentally
>
> Adds a padlock icon that allows toggling each tab's lock/unlocked state. When a locked tab is being closed, a confirmation dialog which allows preventing the tab from closing, is displayed.

The author of the extension has indicated that in Chrome,
after you click on the padlock, the extension won't be able
to prevent the tab from being closed until you first interact
(i.e. click anywhere) with the page.

[image]

Comment: I've tried it already and doesn't actually work properly mate

Comment: Hey BTW I just give this a second try and figured out the issue I had with the extension, it was actually very silly, and I though the extension was broken lol. Here's a conversation where the project owner himself addressed it: [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/52VEJ34.png). Anyways now it's working like a charm, and thanks @harrymc to make me to give this a second thought. 

Comment: I added his comment to my answer, useful for future readers.